# Jquery Sort JSON array by relevance based on a search term

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with some search results which are to be displayed in a jQuery datatable. I need to sort the rows I got based on the search term. I mean the most matched rows with the search term should be on top of the search results displayed. For example, if my search term is 'Hello World and my data is as follows.

```
Hello 560 World
Hello Business World Guy
World of Hello
Hello World
100 Hello World's
World Hello Business
```

After sorting, I need to get the sort the array like

```
Hello World    
100 Hello World's
Hello 560 World
Hello Business World Guy
World of Hello
World Hello Business
```

Is there any JavaScript / jQuery function to do this? I just need to get the rearranged array with the most matched rows at the beginning.

Comment: Even if you get the data as JSON, as soon as you parsed it you are working with a normal JavaScript array. So your problem has nothing to do with JSON and I will edit it accordingly. For your actual question, have a look at `Array#sort`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort. Then you  have to figure out how to determine which rows match "the most".

Comment: here's a `fuzzy search` library that might help  http://kiro.me/projects/fuse.html

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want fuzzy string matching. Check out fuzzyset.js for a javascript solution.

http://glench.github.io/fuzzyset.js