# Merge and sort multiple JavaScript arrays by relevance based on a search term

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I think [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136288/jquery-sort-json-array-by-relevance-based-on-a-search-term) to this has been asked before but I cant seem to figure it out. I have two arrays from an SQL database in my cordova app. Is it possible to combine these two arrays and order by the best match to the search query.

In my app I have a search function that searches multiple local tables and orders by the best match. This works fine

SQL Query Example:

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE f_name LIKE ? ORDER BY (CASE WHEN f_name = ? THEN 1 WHEN f_name LIKE ? THEN 2 ELSE 3 END), f_name ",["%" + query + "%", query, query + "%"],onSuccess, onError);
```

This process is repeated and different arrays are created for the the different tables being searched.

I am left with 2 tables one for users and one for message content. After the SQL queries have run the call back function then sorts all the results into 1 array:

```
var allResults = [];
// create an array of all

for(var x = 0; x < allChatSearchResults.users.length; x++){
    var result = allChatSearchResults.users[x];
    result['type'] = 'user';
    allResults[allResults.length] = result;
}
for(var x = 0; x < allChatSearchResults.messages.length; x++){
    var result = allChatSearchResults.messages[x];
    result['type'] = 'message';
    allResults[allResults.length] = result;
}
```

Is there a method i can use to loop through the array **allResults** and reorder this array to match the search query.

The array output is like this for a search of 'user':

```
allResults = [
{
    type : 'user',
    f_name : 'username',
    l_name : 'somename'
},
{
    type : 'message',
    message : 'this is my user name', //////   query from sql matches this
    date : '11/04/2016'
},
{
    type : 'message',
    message : 'another containing username', //////   query from sql matches this
    date : '09/04/2016'
},
//and so on
];
```

Full Code:

```
var searchResultsSource = 0;
var allChatSearchResults = {users : [], messages : []};
var searchChatResults = function (type, query, res){
    searchResultsSource++;
    if(res.length > 0){
        for(var x = 0; x < res.length; x++){ allChatSearchResults[type][x] = res[x]; }
    }
    if(searchResultsSource == 2){
        //run the function
        console.log('Search Results', allChatSearchResults);
        var allResults = [];
        //  create an array of all
        for(var x = 0; x < allChatSearchResults.users.length; x++){
            var result = allChatSearchResults.users[x];
            result['type'] = 'user';
            allResults[allResults.length] = result;
        }
        for(var x = 0; x < allChatSearchResults.messages.length; x++){
            var result = allChatSearchResults.messages[x];
            result['type'] = 'message';
            allResults[allResults.length] = result;
        }
        //  create an array of just search query

        //  reorder the array based on the ordered search query


    }
};
var searchChats = function () {
    var query = $('#activeChatSearch').val();
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    if(query.length > 3){
        //search my chats
        //search users and search messages
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            var users = [];
            var chats = [];
            var messages = [];
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE f_name LIKE ? ORDER BY (CASE WHEN f_name = ? THEN 1 WHEN f_name LIKE ? THEN 2 ELSE 3 END), f_name ",["%" + query + "%", query, query + "%"], function (tx, res){
                if(res.rows.length == 0){ console.log('no users with first name ' + query); }
                for(var x = 0; x < res.rows.length; x++){ users[x] = res.rows.item(x); }
                searchChatResults('users', query, users);
            }, function (tx, error){
                console.log(error.message);
            });
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM active_chats ORDER BY last_changed DESC", [], function (tx, res){
                if(res.rows.length > 0){
                    var count = 0;
                    var max = res.rows.length;
                    var results = res.rows;
                    var searchThisChat = function (tx, query, chatID){
                        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM chat_" + chatID + " WHERE message LIKE ? ORDER BY (CASE WHEN message = ? THEN 1 WHEN message LIKE ? THEN 2 ELSE 3 END), message LIMIT 0,1", ["%" + query + "%", query, query + "%"], function (tx, res){
                            if(res.rows.length == 0){ /*console.log('No chats match query',messages); */ }
                            else { messages[messages.length] = res.rows.item(0); }
                            if(count == max){ searchChatResults('messages', query, messages); } else{ searchThisChat(tx, query, results.item(count).chat_id); count++; }
                        }, function (tx, e){
                            console.log(e.message);
                            if(count == max){ searchChatResults('messages', query, messages); } else{ searchThisChat(tx, query, results.item(count).chat_id); count++; }
                        });
                    };
                    searchThisChat(tx, query, res.rows.item(0).chat_id);
                }
            }, function (tx, e){
                console.log(e.message);
            });
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('Open database ERROR: ', err);
        });

        var activeChats = $('#activeChats');
        activeChats.html('');
        for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++){
            var item = formatCurrentChatItem(
                {f_name : query, l_name : 'Bloggs', 'user_id' : 18},
                null,
                null
            );
            item.appendTo(activeChats);
        }
    }
};
$(function () {
    $('#activeChatSearch').on('input', searchChats);
    $('#activeChatSearchBtn').on('click', searchChats);  <-   input function
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Provide a sample input and required output

Comment: Ill stick the full function in, i just tried to shorten down a bit as it quite long

Comment: Your edit is (unfortunately) a bad edit. Your full code is not needed. You need to provide **sample input and required output**. If you have a failed attempt to do that include the relevant code (**only** the relevant code).

Comment: How do you relate the user object with the message object? Is the username in the message same with `f_name` for instance?

Comment: Its not the client asked to have a search bar that searched for users and messages containing the search query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not including the relevance score in the returned SQL, there is no way to combine two arrays.

First you need to return the score as part of your SQL:

`tx.executeSql("SELECT *,(CASE WHEN f_name = ? THEN 1 WHEN f_name LIKE ? THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) as Score FROM contacts WHERE f_name LIKE ? ORDER BY (CASE WHEN f_name = ? THEN 1 WHEN f_name LIKE ? THEN 2 ELSE 3 END), f_name ",["%" + query + "%", query, query + "%"],onSuccess, onError);`

Then you will be able to combine the arrays and sort by the 'Score' column:

`allResults.sort(function(a,b){ return a.Score-b.Score; });`

Comment: wow didnt know I could do that, turns out it was an sql matter not javascript.  Thanks @binarymax

Comment: Happy to help @PaulLedger. If this answered your question, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: No problem @binarymax